# How to run multiple Perl-CGI on IIS

Tags: iis, cgi

I have one perl CGI script processing local data based on user request through IIS. User can start the CGI script with arguments by http.  For one-request-one-instance scenario, this works fine.

The next scenario is that multiple requests happens simultaneously. The IIS will start each CGI script for each request. This generates concurrency issue. The question is whether IIS can handle this concurrency situation, ideally no-blocking fashion?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use FastCGI to speed up the CGI and Catalyst for Web Framework.